# How do I use Tkinter with Python on Windows Vista?

Tags: python, windows, windows-vista, tkinter

I installed Python 2.6 for one user on Windows Vista.  Python works okay, but when I try: `import Tkinter`, it says the side-by-side configuration has errors.  I've tried tinkering with the Visual Studio runtime, with no good results.  Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should downgrade to 2.5 version?

Answer (score 1):

It seems this is a one of the many weird Vista problems and some random reinstalling, installing/upgrading of the visual studio runtime or some such seems sometimes to help, or disabling sxs in the system configuration or writing a manifest file etc.

Though I think you should downgrade to windows XP.

Comment: Can you clarify why Visual Studio would have an effect on this?

Comment: If you search for "side-by-side configuration has errors" on google a lot of the entries mess around something with Visual studio and going from 2005 to 2008 and some specifically mention installing an upgrade to the runtime.

Comment: Tried it last night - it didn't make any difference for Tkinter.

Answer (score -1):

python 2.6.2 + tkinter 8.5, no problems

Comment: Yes - they've fixed it by now.